# How to add "<li>" into "<ul>" using jquery?

Tags: jquery

Can someone help adding to 'li' into 'ul'. not sure what im missing here. I have html in a variable

Below is the code snippet

```js
var myhtml = "<div><ul></ul></div>";
var msg = "<li>some message</li>";
$(myhtml).find("ul").append(msg);
$("#mycontainer").append(myhtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=mycontainer>My Div</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You almost had it, but you forgot to append your list to the div. Just try doing it like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=mycontainer>My Div</div>

<script>
  var myhtml = "<div><ul></ul></div>";
  var msg = "<li>some message</li>";

  $(mycontainer).append($(myhtml).find("ul").append(msg))
</script>
```

Here's a [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/gopodilixo/edit) with a working version.

Comment: Thanks @Marcos this is working, I thought when i do $(myhtml).find("ul").append(msg) it will update instance of 'myhtml' variable and then i can append the instance to div container.  But 'myhtml' instance doesn't get updated

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick, but I'm sure there will be a neater way, you could fiddle with this a little more and make it more minimal and concise.

```js
var div = "<div></div>";

var li = "<li>Some Message</li>";
var ul = $("<ul></ul>").append(li);

var constructor = $(div).append(ul);

$('#mycontainer').append(constructor);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=mycontainer>My Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myhtml = "<div><ul></ul></div>";
var msg = "<li>some message</li>";
$("#mycontainer").append(myhtml);
$("#mycontainer").find("ul").append(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mycontainer">My Div</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UL` doesn't exist yet therefore you can't append to it at that point. Change it around like so and it should work.

```js
var myhtml = "<div><ul></ul></div>";
var msg = "<li>some message</li>";
$("#mycontainer").append(myhtml);
$("#mycontainer div ul").append(msg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=mycontainer>My Div</div>
```